# XNA Xbox, utilizing multiple cores

Tags: xna, c#, multithreading, xbox360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XNA: How does threading work?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/680/xna-how-does-threading-work)

It's my understanding that the Xbox has 3 cores that are available to use. I'm hoping to offload AI to another core, and possibly use another core to see if certain objects are on screen(if so they will be added to a list to be drawn).

How would I go about doing this? It needs to be compatible on the xbox360.

Comment: You don't specify which core does what, you create threads and those get scheduled.

Comment: @Byte56 I didn't think this was the case for the Xbox. All threads get executed on the same core by default - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xnaframework/thread/23f0bf4c-588f-4006-b2f2-c84e496bdfd9

Comment: @RayDey Fair enough, seems like XBox allows a bit more control. It's still a duplicate.